# Use dict values as counter in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Need to return 2 dictionaries where the one has to have **counter** **keys** (that works well) and the second one has to have **counter** **values**

```
with io.open(file_name, 'r', encoding='ISO-8859-1') as f:
    c = 0
    rid_to_name = {}
    name_to_rid = {}

    for line in f:
        line = line.split(',')    
        rid_to_name[c] = line[1]
        name_to_rid[line[1]] = c
        c +=1

    return rid_to_name, name_to_rid
```

Outputs:

```
print(rid_to_name)
{0: '6597', 1: '6599', 2: '6601', 3: '7202', 4: '7419', 5: '7424'

print(name_to_rid)
{'6597': 2034, '6599': 2183, '6601': 1963, '7202': 1470, '7419': 2608
```

I want the dictionary for value output has this structure but instead it works kinda strange for me.

```
print(name_to_rid)
{'6597': 1 '6599': 2, '6601': 3, '7202': 4, '7419': 5
```

BTW, it works well with lines, when I don't use counter. May someone tells me how to get what I want and explain why dictionary works exactly this way with counters. Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the value of line in the iteration?

Comment: `rid_to_name[c] = line[1]` is generating a dict the same length as the number of lines. this is working because you increment c with every line. `name_to_rid[line[1]] = c` on the other hand writes on a given key multiple times, so it holds the line number where the key was last found.

Comment: Your question is not clear, this is why you did not get useful help till now. Try to describe the problem you want to solve not your idea of how to solve. We can read the code anyway. Maybe you misunderstood dictionaries and want to use lists.

Answer (score -1):

It could be useful for you to check `collections.Counter` class here:

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

It does what you need.

Comment: Collections Counter is kinda not what I want, I don't want to count times of appearing elements etc. I need to add my own counter that just works as increment for each line(the other words, for each key in the dictionary). But thanks a lot, anytyme